# sys_ functions in syscalls.h are undefined

Tags: c, linux, kernel, system-calls

I'm just making a kernel module.
And I meet this warnings:

```
WARNING: "sys_getpid" [/PATH/NAME.ko] undefined!
WARNING: "sys_stat" [/PATH/NAME.ko] undefined!
WARNING: "sys_rmdir" [/PATH/NAME.ko] undefined!
WARNING: "sys_mremap" [/PATH/NAME.ko] undefined!
WARNING: "sys_fchmod" [/PATH/NAME.ko] undefined!
WARNING: "sys_gettimeofday" [/PATH/NAME.ko] undefined!
WARNING: "sys_utimes" [/PATH/NAME.ko] undefined!
WARNING: "sys_fcntl" [/PATH/NAME.ko] undefined!
WARNING: "sys_getcwd" [/PATH/NAME.ko] undefined!
WARNING: "sys_unlink" [/PATH/NAME.ko] undefined!
WARNING: "localtime" [/PATH/NAME.ko] undefined!
WARNING: "sys_write" [/PATH/NAME.ko] undefined!
WARNING: "sys_fsync" [/PATH/NAME.ko] undefined!
WARNING: "sys_fchown" [/PATH/NAME.ko] undefined!
WARNING: "sys_ftruncate" [/PATH/NAME.ko] undefined!
WARNING: "sys_fstat" [/PATH/NAME.ko] undefined!
WARNING: "sys_munmap" [/PATH/NAME.ko] undefined!
WARNING: "sys_geteuid" [/PATH/NAME.ko] undefined!
WARNING: "sys_read" [/PATH/NAME.ko] undefined!
WARNING: "sys_access" [/PATH/NAME.ko] undefined!
WARNING: "sys_old_mmap" [/PATH/NAME.ko] undefined!
WARNING: "errno" [/PATH/NAME.ko] undefined!
WARNING: "getenv" [/PATH/NAME.ko] undefined!
WARNING: "sys_mkdir" [/PATH/NAME.ko] undefined!
WARNING: "sys_time" [/PATH/NAME.ko] undefined!
WARNING: "sys_lseek" [/PATH/NAME.ko] undefined!
WARNING: "sysconf" [/PATH/NAME.ko] undefined!
```

How can I fix this problem?

This is my codes:

```
#include <linux/string.h>
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <linux/syscalls.h>
#include <linux/fs.h>
#include <linux/delay.h>
#include <linux/slab.h>
#include <linux/types.h>
#include <linux/stat.h>
#include <linux/fcntl.h>
#include <asm-generic/unistd.h>
#include <uapi/asm-generic/fcntl.h>
#include <linux/time.h>
#include <linux/errno.h>
#include <linux/mman.h>

// And use functions(sys_open, sys_write, ...)
```

And my workspace is Ubuntu 3.13.0-66-generic.

I need to use file descriptor.
So, I can't use `filp_` functions(like `filp_open`).

#### Edit1:

My Makefile:
    obj-m += NAME.o

```
NAME-objs := FILE1.o FILE2.o FILE3.o FILE4.o

ccflags-y := -mhard-float -msse -mpreferred-stack-boundary=4 -w -I/usr/include -I/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/
ldflags-y += -lpthread -ldl


KDIR := /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build
PWD := $(shell pwd)

default:
    $(MAKE) -C $(KDIR) SUBDIRS=$(PWD) modules 

clean:
    rm -rf *.ko *.mod *.cmd *.o *.mod.c *.order *.symvers  .tmp_versions
```

Comment: the code may also need something like: `#include <asm-i386/unistd.h>`

Comment: the warnings are coming from the linker, which means either the linker parameters are incorrect (lib paths then lib names need to be last on the list of parameters) or the necessary library is not listed in the linker command line

Comment: Can you post the command you are using to build your module?

Comment: @SashaPachev I added my makefile after saw your comment. Thank you for your attention

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling system calls(`sys_*` functions) from the kernel code is not a good idea. Actually, many of system calls can be expressed in functions, available for kernel modules.

> I need to use file descriptor. So, I can't use filp_ functions(like filp_open).

File descriptor can be easy transformed into file pointer using `fdget`. See, e.g., implementation of fallocate system call (`SYSCALL_DEFINE4(fallocate...)` in `fs/open.h`).

As for `errno`, this variable is user space only. System calls return error using `-E` convention, it is libc who stores this value into `errno`.